# What's the recommended way of iterating a container in C++11?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++11

What's the recommended way of iterating a container in C++11?

Using

```
container.begin() and container.end()
```

Or

```
begin(container) and end(container)
```

If any, when is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Your examples have nothing to do with iterating per se. It's about how to get iterators from an object of a class that is a model of  container.

Comment: There is no yet enough experience to have recommanded ways. The new for syntax and the begin/end free functions have advantages, but there may be drawbacks experience will tell about (I expect none, but I didn't expect most of the teachings of experience, even when I expected some).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The better way is

```
begin(container)
end(container)
```

because it's more extensible. For example, template argument deduction can be used to determine the size of a static array and hence `begin(my_static_array)` and `end(my_static_array)` will work.

More generally, you can add overloads/specialisations to begin(.) end(.) and use immutable legacy types in generic algorithms.

You really only need to worry about this if you're writing a generic algorithm youself

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T & t)
{
    bar (begin(t), end(t)); // certainly better than bar(t.begin(), t.end())
}
```

In client code it doesn't matter so much. In fact, I would say *don't* use the new form in that case -- I like to reserve certain styles/idioms for certain circumstances, divide my mindsets. But that's just me.

```
for (auto i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i)
   // I can see at-a-glance that c is a STL-style container.
   // That might be useful to know. I can probably dismiss static arrays
   // and unorthodox containers as possibilities.
   foo (i, c.size());
```

Comment: Why take a reference to an iterator here?

Comment: Because I got scrambled with `for (auto & i : c)`, removed now. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to enable iterating over an array, you have to either write `std::begin(t)` and `std::end(t)`, or you have to write `using std::begin;` and `using std::end;` as the first two statements inside the function (kind of like the `using std::swap` idiom).

Comment: @spraff: As a recommended idiom, I would expect to "cache" the result of `c.end()` during the first statement of the `for` loop instead of computing it at each iteration.

Comment: @MatthieuM., or I could let the compiler worry about micro-optimisations and decline to garnish my answer with noise.

Comment: @spraff: the think is that you don't know whether it is a micro-optimization or not. If the `end` call cannot be inlined and if the compiler cannot prove its purity (pretty rare...), then the optimization won't be performed.

Comment: I can take a fair guess, or I might just [have better things to do with my time](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html). Anyway, the real issue is whether it is relevant to the question in hand. It isn't. Why clutter the answers?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Good point, but (counterintuitively?) I've seen experts advocate using the `using` declarations rather than writing `std::begin(t)` etc., since only the former allows the author of the datatype to provide their own `begin()` and `end()` free functions in their own namespace in such a way that they will be found by argument-dependent name lookup. I can't right now recall why, but the alternative (i.e. writing `std::begin(t)` and expecting the datatype provider to overload the base `std::begin()` template) was held to be dangerous...

Answer (score 37):

I think the new syntax with [range based for loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for-loop)

```
 for (auto item : container)
```

is probably the most C++11 like.

As others commented, you sometimes want `auto&` or  `const auto&` instead of `auto`.

Comment: @Basile: I agree, but VS10 doesn't support that yet so I've not yet played with it. :)

Comment: @spraff: Agreed, but the question was (intentionally?) vague, and my answer fits!

Comment: I'd take take the items as a reference: `auto& item : container`, to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: Actually, you answered a different question :-/

Comment: @Johann: then if you want VS10 support, you don't really want C++11.

Comment: If you looked at the link, or are further familiar with auto, you can specify extra fields , like auto & it: container , if you wanted to modify. The link as shows how static arrays work just fine with range based for loops.

Comment: @spraff: I kindly disagree, the title speaks about iterating over a container, and the range-based for loop certainly iterates over the container while shielding you from many minute mistakes that any other loop might suffer. The code examples provided by the OP do not really concern iterating a container (more getting iterators from it...) but the question is still there.